# Conditionally delete fields from the payment page in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good evening, I have a small problem with my website, I would need when you buy a product and select that the local pickup does not show some fields of the form such as province, postal address or city, if you select for example another shipment as free shipping if they appear. (I think it makes all the sense in the world and I think it's a mistake that it does not come pre-defined like this)

The website is made with Wordpress and Woocommerce, I have tried practically everything and there is no way to work, the functions that I have found here do not end up running any, I do not know if it depends on the theme (Flatsome) or the version of Woocommerce

Thank you very much for your time.

Greetings.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Comment: Hello Justin R, without problem, the function that I am using is the following one: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-shipping-local-pickup-selected/

The problem I have is that this hides the entire container of billing data (I just want some of them to be hidden)

Comment: I am also testing with this function (I think it is very appropriate for my case), but it does absolutely nothing, what can be the error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498391/remove-selected-checkout-fields-with-woocommerce-depending-on-shipping-method