# Remove Selected Checkout Fields with Woocommerce Depending on Shipping Method Redux

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In reference to this [Remove selected checkout fields with woocommerce depending on shipping method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498391/remove-selected-checkout-fields-with-woocommerce-depending-on-shipping-method)

How can I adapt the codes in order remove different fields based on different shipping methods selected?

I've tried modifying the beginnging part to below, but it just stops working...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields' );
function xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    // uncomment below line and reload checkout page to check current $chosen_methods
    // print_r($chosen_methods);
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == 'flat_rate:13') {
        $shipping_method = 'flat_rate:13';
        $hide_fields = array( 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_state', 'billing_postcode' );
    }

    if ($chosen_shipping =='flat_rate:7') { 
        $shipping_method = 'flat_rate:7';
        $hide_fields = array( 'billing_city', 'billing_state', 'billing_postcode' );
    }

    foreach($hide_fields as $field ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
            $fields['billing'][$field]['required'] = false;
            $fields['billing'][$field]['class'][] = 'hide';
        }
        $fields['billing'][$field]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic';
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

The other part looks like this, which I copied and modified from another answer

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_script', 999 );
function cart_update_script() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <style>
        .hide {display: none!important;}
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {

            // woocommerce_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }

            var show = ['flar_rate:7', 'flat_rate:13'];

            $(document).on( 'change', '#shipping_method input[type="radio"]', function() {
              // console.log($.inArray($(this).val(), show));
              if ($.inArray($(this).val(), show) > -1) {    // >-1 if found in array
                $('.billing-dynamic').removeClass('hide');
                // console.log('show');
              } else {
                $('.billing-dynamic').addClass('hide');
                // console.log('hide');
              }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Also, if I change the country, which changes also the shipping zone, the fields ain't reverted until I select the shipping method again.

Thanks in advance.